# JOGL vertices limited between 0f and 1f

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, perspective

I'm making a basic 3DS model viewer using JOGL, and I found that if I don't scale the vertices it won't display properly.  Say if the max vertex value was 40, I would scale all others by this to force the vertices to be between 0 and 1, then draw it.  Is there a way to set the perspective so I don't have to scale values? If it helps, the GLCanvas size I'm using is 600x600.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to set the perspective so I don't have to scale values? I

Of course. In old fixed function pipeline OpenGL you'd have the *projection* and *modelview* matrices to apply transformations on. Today, in modern shader based OpenGL you can implement whatever transformation you like in the vertex shader.

I suggest you read some OpenGL tutorials to get a firm grip on the subject, rather than wander in the foggy dark. I suggest http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut